# Is fighting for Allah only allowed when one is stronger than non-believers?

Tags: fiqh, allah, jihad

One should only (with hand and tongue) fight for his believe when he is in the stronger position and non-believers are against Islamic religion. But as long as one is in the weaker position one should not fight (with hand and tongue) for Allah, even when non-believers are talking against Islamic religion.

Is this true? Even when they are talking against Islamic religion?

Please answer with citations of the Quran!

PS: I read that in the internet but I cannot recall exactly where it was and I wondered if there are texts in the Quran about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being passive in weakness is a concession in certain circumstances, not an order and not even endorsed.

> انفروا **خفافا وثقالا** وجاهدوا بأموالكم وأنفسكم في سبيل الله ذلكم خير لكم إن كنتم تعلمون
>
> Go forth, **whether light or heavy**, and strive with your wealth and your lives in the cause of Allah. That is better for you, if you only knew.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:41](http://quran.com/9/41)</sup>

In much of the wars in early Islam the Muslims were mostly weaker, outnumbered or ill-equipped.

> فإن يكن منكم مائة صابرة يغلبوا مائتين وإن يكن منكم ألف يغلبوا ألفين بإذن الله
>
> So if there are from you one hundred [who are] steadfast, they will overcome two hundred. And if there are among you a thousand, they will overcome two thousand by permission of Allah.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 8:66](http://quran.com/8/66)</sup>

> قل للمخلفين من الأعراب ستدعون إلى قوم أولي بأس شديد تقاتلونهم أو يسلمون فإن تطيعوا يؤتكم الله أجرا حسنا وإن تتولوا كما توليتم من قبل يعذبكم عذابا أليما
>
> Say to those who remained behind of the bedouins, "You will be called to [face] a people of great military might; you may fight them, or they will submit. So if you obey, Allah will give you a good reward; but if you turn away as you turned away before, He will punish you with a painful punishment."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 48:16](http://quran.com/48/16)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Someone who does not believe, for them it seems like victory comes through strength and number. It only seems logical. But we Muslims believe in the unseen and that you can also have the help from Allah. Therefore you might be smaller in number and strength, but Allah might have sent down thousands of angels to help you. This is recorded in the Quran:

There was a token for you in two hosts which met: one army fighting in the way of Allah, and another disbelieving, whom they saw as twice their number, clearly, with their very eyes. Thus Allah strengtheneth with His succour whom He will. Lo! herein verily is a lesson for those who have eyes. (3:13)

When thou didst say unto the believers: Is it not sufficient for you that your Lord should support you with three thousand angels sent down (to your help)? (3:124) Nay, but if ye persevere, and keep from evil, and (the enemy) attack you suddenly, your Lord will help you with five thousand angels sweeping on. (3:125) Allah ordained this only as a message of good cheer for you, and that thereby your hearts might be at rest - Victory cometh only from Allah, the Mighty, the Wise - (3:126)

As a Muslim in a fight you should rely and put their trust on Allah, not on your number and strength.

If Allah is your helper none can overcome you, and if He withdraw His help from you, who is there who can help you after Him? In Allah let believers put their trust. (3:160)

Allah loves those who put their trust in him.

Answer (score 0):

As‘salaamu alaikum.

Dear brother, weakness and strength is relative in this world. If you fight only when you think you are strong then that doesn‘t say much about your faith and trust in Allah.

Truth #1: STRENGTH DOES NOT GUARANTEE VICTORY.

“Assuredly, Allah did help you in many battle-fields on the day of Hunain. BEHOLD! YOUR GREAT NUMBERS ELATED YOU, BUT THEY AVAILED YOU NOTHING. The land, for all that it is wide did constrain you, AND YOU TURNED BACK IN RETREAT.” Qur‘an 9:25

Truth #2: WEAKNESS DOES NOT GUARANTEE DEFEAT.

“When they crossed the river - (Taloot) and the faithful ones with him - they said, ‘We cannot cope with Goliath and his forces this day.‘ But those who were certain that they must meet Allah said, ‘How often, by Allah‘s Will, has a small force defeated a big one? Allah is with those who patiently persevere.‘ When they advanced to Goliath and his forces, they prayed, ‘Our Lord! Pour out constancy upon us and make our feet firm. And help us against the rejectors of faith.‘ BY ALLAH‘S WILL THEY (Taloot and the faithful) ROUTED THEM.” Qur‘an 2:249-251

From these passages (and i could‘ve cited more!) we see that it‘s not about “strength” and “weakness”. It‘s really  about faith, patieoce and constancy (sabr), and trusting in Allah. That‘s our part. The Qadr of Allah determines everything else.

I hope this answer helped you. Ma‘as.‘salaam.